Can't upgrade from 20.04 to 22.04 (GUI or CLI)
I've been wasting too much time on this. I follow all the steps I've found online but I don't seem able to upgrade Ubuntu neither from terminal or GUI.
Any ideas how to "force an upgrade"? (Without making my workstation unusable.)
Via command line
Prepare for upgrade
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo apt dist-upgrade
sudo do-release-upgrade

Upgrade
> sudo do-release-upgrade
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Please install all available updates for your release before upgrading.

Via GUI
Firstly the package doesn't show

Which goes away if I just click settings and then close (go figure)

However when I click on Upgrade... nothing happens.

Your last picture shows a problem if its current; ie. 22.04.4 should have been shown for 2+ months now (https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2024/02/22/ubuntu-22-04-4-lts-released/).  I'd start with sudo apt update & check for no warnings, missing lines etc... as your details do show a system that hasn't been fully upgraded OR your details are rather old.

@guiverc good catch. Thanks.
